# Can I set programs to automatically install to F:/program files?

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning

I have put my Windows XP install on a partioned 3gb drive (please tell me know if this is **not** a good idea) and intend to keep Documents and Settings and Program Files on the remainder partitioned portion (247gb).

Is there a way to make installers/Windows assume the F: drive (the bigger partition)?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the location of your program files directories in the registry in the following keys.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CommonFilesDir
```

Then reboot your system.

However being a software tester as a profession I would recommend **DON'T DO IT**.

Changing the location should work if you can assume that no software has any hard coded paths in the application.

Many, heck most applications use hard coded paths, so this will lead to a very, very unstable system.

I also find that partitioning a disk simply isn't worth the hassle. You'll typically run out of space on your C drive, or have chunks of free space spread across the drives you can't use, and if the disk fails you lose it all anyway.

Edit:
Here's a Link to a Microsoft KB article on the subject http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700

Comment: +1 For the warning and better answer

Comment: Also check out this very valid link with Microsoft's take on the issue (feel free to add this to your answer Bruce) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933700

Comment: @pavsaund Added the link. I know first hand the type of pain this change could make ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think 3gb is a little too small, but that's because I'd rather that the OS-disk had som extra space. I think 5GB should be enough.

In regards to wanting to move your Program Files directory, [check out this link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/sujet-1328-change-the-default-installation-folder-c-program-files)